# Referencing a unique field in another table

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique-key

I have a table that has a primary key and a unique key.

From another table, is it possible to reference this unique key just the way Primary Key's and Foreign Keys are referenced & used ?

Would like to define this in the SQL definitions so that data correlations between these two tables are automatically cross referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys specifically state they only need a unique and not-null key to work. Using a primary key just means it's a unique non-null key.

So, yes you can! You can even reference unique multi-column groups if you need to.

Search for the word "unique" within [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), you'll find further explanations.

Comment: A foreign key can only point to a primary key and this is obvious since all primary key entries are unique. So what is wrong with a Foreign Key pointing to a Unique Key in another table in MYSQL ? If there is a solution, I'd like to know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I've stated in my answer foreign keys **can** point to **unique** keys not necessarily to **primary** keys. So go ahead and define your foreign key to point to the unique key.